# asp.net user able to login after clearing cookies?

Tags: asp.net

After clearing cookies in browser , user is able to navigate to any page? Here i am not clicking on logout I expect once browser cookies are cleared, user should be redirected to login page .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: During active session ? when user is logged in ?

Comment: check this  !!! http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Cookieless-Session-State.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The authentication ticket is stored in either a cookie or the QueryString. I assume, in your website, the authentication ticket is stored in a cookie. Please verify.

By default, users have access to the whole website. If you want to restrict access, you have to configure your website. Typically, this is done in web.config like so:

```
<location path="blah">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This is just a basic example.

If you expand your question, we all can help you more.